# How to keep FK-IK switch from rotating leg bones

Tags: rigging, bones

I recently created a rig using a tutorial on youtube, and it has a driver to switch between FK and IK. However, whenever I switch over to Ik from FK, the leg bones turn about 90 degrees for some reason, screwing up the bottom half of my rig. I've tried messing with my rig settings a little, even attempting to rotate the bones in pose mode, but no luck. Can anyone help me with this? I have the .blend file attached below (as well as some pics).

Blend file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dVgT5jLokOPYeKBvVmrB6AicUjysIMwz/view?usp=sharing

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm getting 'Access Denied' from Google drives.  But that's a common problem and I'm surprised there's not an answer.  Go to the bone constraint and look at 'Pole Angle'.  You need to change the angle until the problem doesn't happen.

Comment: That fixed it! Tysm!
Edit: small problem: the upper legs still turn (i realized it when I reapplied the mesh). Is there a way to ix that as well?

Comment: You probably have a bone with the incorrect roll.  Turn on 'axis' in the bone viewport display panel and show us what that viewport looks like.

Comment: Done. Btw the blend file should now be working too, if u wanna try that.

Comment: Hey, I think I fixed it! I just had to make the roll of the fk the same as the ik :D Ty for ur help!

Comment: you're welcome and great.